# How to configure Netbeans for running cordova app on windows phone?

Tags: cordova, netbeans

Is there any way to configure netbeans for cordova windows phone?
I have installed cordova and I use netbeans for running cordova apps on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, only iOS and Android are supported. If you just want to run it (without debugging), you can define e.g. Grunt task to execute a command (using [grunt-exec plugin](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) ) which runs Cordova project on WP and invoke that task from NetBeans (right click on project and select Grunt tasks)